# File permission issue, when Installing Magento 2 in OSX El Capitan

Tags: php, apache, magento, osx-elcapitan, magento-2.0

I was trying to install Magento 2 in OSX El Capitan system.

For this I was downloaded Magento 2 files from their website and placed in default OSX apache server folder (/Library/Webserver/Documents/Magento). I have made changes in php.ini file as in the Magento installation documents.

I was successfully located the magento installation page using (localhos/magento), but after completing readiliness check it shows some error on file permission.
I had give file permission using "chmod 777 directory", but it wont helps.

Screenshot for the error:

[image: the error]

Comment: please don't post images here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 chmod -R 777 directory
```

for recursive permission setting

This will set all subfolders an files to the 777 Permission

Comment: there's nowhere in the docs recommends 777, please use the commands in https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html as 777 is not great for security

Answer (score 1):

In your magento installation root,Run the four command below.

```
sudo chmod -R 777  app/etc
sudo chmod -R 777 var
```

Above two folder permission are correct in your case.

```
sudo chmod -R 777  pub/media
sudo chmod -R 777 pub/static
```